# Vue - Right way to merge two different types of data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-cli

I am creating an application using `Vue CLI` and `Vuex`. In the initial fetch of my application right after authentication I get two types of data: `Messages` and `Events`

There is a place in my application where I need to merge `Messages` and `Events` based on chronological order using the `created_at` attribute.

This is the `Messages` structure:

```
var messages = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Message 01',
    created_at: '2019-01-28T11:00:00+00:00'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Message 02',
    created_at: '2019-01-28T13:00:00+00:00'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Message 03',
    created_at: '2019-01-28T15:00:00+00:00'
  }
]
```

This is the `Events` structure:

```
var events = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Event 01',
    created_at: '2019-01-28T10:00:00+00:00'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Event 02',
    created_at: '2019-01-28T12:00:00+00:00'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Event 03',
    created_at: '2019-01-28T14:00:00+00:00'
  }
]
```

After merge everything I want to use a loop to display `Messages` and `Events` in chronological order.

This is the html structure to be used:

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container .message{
  background: red;
  margin-left: auto;
}

.container .event{
  background: blue;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="message">Message</div>
  <div class="event">Event</div>
</div>
```

After receive this data from the store what is the correct way to merge both? And after merge which way to properly loop to display each `Message` or `Event` in your specific `div`?

Comment: You would do this to the data before it ever got to Vue.

Comment: @RobertHarvey The API I own sends me all the data separately, I need to do this within the application

Comment: @CaioKawasaki You might want to do the merging logic on a [`computed` getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#getters).

Comment: @jom Yes, but, how to handle the diferences? When inside the `loop` to show the data...

Comment: @CaioKawasaki What do you mean by "handling the differences"? When merged, they should be one sole entity (of type array), right? How are you going to merge them though?

Comment: @jom after merge, if the object be a `message` it should be render inside `<div class="message"></div>` and if an `event` should be `<div class="event"></div>`. I just mentioned 2 types of data but as the application grows there may be others.

Comment: So basically you want to group them by the type of data. While merging, you could add a single type identifier on the individual items and use this to decide which item goes to which div.

Comment: @jom if I merge two items from different type with same Id, problems can come up, right?

Comment: @CaioKawasaki Is the `item.name` going to be consistent? If so, why not decide on type by the substring of it?

Comment: @jom the name will not be consistent, it will be random strings from the database

Answer (score 0):

3 things to do:

- No need to transform API data directly, use computed values from 2 arrays.
- Add identifier to inform rendering logic the type of item in array. A boolean `isMessage` will do.
- Add new unique id for items in array if your ids for messages and events could be similar.

If you use vuex, the good way is to use getters to get the computed value. In here I will provide a sample of using Vue's computed.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div v-for="item in combinedArray" :key="item.combinedId">
            <div v-if="item.isMessage">this is a message</div>
            <div v-else>this is an event</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    props: [ 'messages', 'events' ],
    computed: {
        combinedArray() {
            const array = [
                ...this.messages.map(m => ({
                    combinedId: `message_${m.id}`,
                    isMessage: true,
                    ...m
                })),
                ...this.events.map(e => ({
                    combinedId: `event_${e.id}`,
                    isMessage: false,
                    ...e
                }))
            ]
            return array.sort((itemA, itemB) => new Date(itemA.created_at) - new Date(itemB.created_at))
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can just do `return array.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.created_at) - new Date(a.created_at))`

Comment: @EricGuan thanks for your suggestion. Updated the answer